# Show that the sequence $(1+N^2)/[N(1+N)]-5/6$ is positive and increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-writing

I have the function
\begin{equation*}
    f(N)= \frac{1+N^2}{N(1+N)}-\frac{5}{6},
\end{equation*}
where $N\in\mathbb{Z}_{++}/\{1, 2\}$.
I want to show that $f(N)>0$ and that $f(N+1)>f(N)$ for all $N>3$ since $f(3)=0$.

**Approach 1: Continuous Extension**

Define a new continuous function $g$ on $x\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$, where
\begin{equation*}
    g(x)=\frac{1+x^2}{x(1+x)} \text{ and }  g'(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2-2}{x^2(1+x)^2}.
\end{equation*}
The numerator of $g'(x)$ has a positive root at $x=1+\sqrt{2}$.
Moreover, $\frac{d}{dx}[(x-1)^2-2]=2(x-1)>0$ for $x>1$.
Therefore, $g(x)$ is an increasing function for any $x>1$ and is positive for any $x>1+\sqrt{2}$.
Taken together, $g(x)>0$ for any $x>3$.
However, I'm not sure of how legitimate an approach this is or how to relate these results back to my integer function to write a proper proof.

**Approach 2: Induction**

Let $N=4$ then $f(4)=1/60$. Take $f(N)>0$ to be true, then I need to show that
\begin{equation*}
    f(N+1)=\frac{1+(N+1)^2}{(N+1)[1+(N+1)]}>\frac{5}{6}.
\end{equation*}
Apart from simplifying the above somewhat, I'm not sure what the next step(s) would be. In induction proofs that I have read, often the presumption that $f(N)>0$ would play a role in showing that $f(N+1)>0$, but I don't see a clear way to do that.

**Approach 3: Difference or quotient**

This seems more related to showing that $f$ is increasing than showing it's positive but looking at
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{1+(N+1)^2}{(N+1)[1+(N+1)]}-\frac{1+N^2}{N(1+N)}>0
\end{equation*}
or \begin{equation*}
    \frac{\frac{1+(N+1)^2}{(N+1)[1+(N+1)]}}{\frac{1+N^2}{N(1+N)}}>1.
\end{equation*}

Any help or advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: $f(N)$ is not an integer-valued function.  For example, $f(4)=1/60\not\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you for the correction. I have adjusted the title accordingly.

Comment: A shorter name is *sequence*.

Comment: @RobPratt Ah that's interesting, I had not thought about it like that but of course you are right: $\{f(3), f(4), \ldots\}$ is a sequence. I'm implicitly using ideas from sequences in Approach 3, I think.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your first approach! All you need to do is note that the output of your continuous function is equal that of your original function for integer inputs and that since your continuous function is increasing for all inputs in the range $[3,\infty)$, so too is your original function (since its domain is a subset of your continuous function's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach that does not rely on calculus.  To see that $f(N)$ is positive, rewrite as $$f(N) = \frac{(N-2)(N-3)}{6N(N+1)},$$
which is $>0$ when $N>3$.
To see that $f(N)$ is increasing, compute
$$f(N+1)-f(N) = \frac{N-2}{N(N+1)(N+2)},$$
which is $>0$ when $N>2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great and just the type of thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(N) := \frac{1+N^2}{N(N+1)}$ can have its domain extended to the positive reals; indeed for each $x>0$ define $f(x) := \frac{1+x^2}{x(x+1)}$.

If $f'(x)$ is positive for all $x \ge x_0$ then $f$ is increasing function on $(x_0,\infty)$. Thus, for all real numbers $y',y>0$ with $y'>y$, the inequality $f(y') > f(y)$ holds. Thus, for all *integers* $N \ge x_0$ it follows that $f(N+1) > f(N)$ [indeed, set $y=N$ and $N+1=y'$ and note the previous sentence]. Thus, as you have shown that $f'(x)$ is positive for all $x \ge 3$, it follows that for all integers $N \ge 3$ the inequality $f(N) < f(N+1)$ holds.

So to show that $f(N)$ is at least $\frac{5}{6}$ for all positive integers $N$, all you need to do is check $f(1),f(2)$, and $f(3)$. Then if all of $f(1),f(2),f(3)$ are at least $\frac{5}{6}$, simply use the fact that $f$ is increasing to conclude $f(N)$ must be at least $f(3) > \frac{5}{6}$ for all other positive integers $N$, equivalently, all integers $N > 3$, as well as $N=1,2,3$.